# PATCH request 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, apache, http

I've recently tried installing a OpenSource Package called EspoCRM
It uses **PATCH** requests to edit records. Yet I can't seem to get it working propperly.

I've installed it on a Linux Apache server with PHP 5.4.31. I tried to set all CHMOD to 777 as a test but that didn't help it.

I've contacted the creator what I'm doing wrong. He thinks my server might be blocking PATCH requests. So I installed it on a XAMPP test on my Destkop and that worked fine.
Yet I can't find any way to deny or allow PATCH requests.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: If I grab the request URL and just open the URL in a new tab it opens correctly. It just doens't handle the request

Comment: How is Apache configured?

Comment: Well it is set up for DirectAdmin so depends on what setting you are looking for.

Comment: this is the vhost definition http://pastebin.com/n4AUxJBJ

Comment: what happens if you add LIMIT in your DIRECTORY Section ?: https://gist.github.com/rcro/a457a3ebef9c8823eb4c

Comment: Oke write that as an answer that totaly worked thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vhost needs permission to handle methods like PATCH.

Add the LIMIT rules like below in your directory section in the vhost config:

```
  <Limit GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS PATCH>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </Limit>
```

Comment: Hero! Saved my day :)!