# 403 Forbidden How to enable Put request in the apache server

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

On put request via ajax "403 forbidden access to server" is thrown on the page.I am using a shared hosting envirnoment.I dont have access to Server. I have checked related questions here but didn't see a solution that helps me.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

My htaccess file look like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

my question is possible duplicate of this question **[PATCH request 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196804/patch-request-403-forbidden)**
But I dont know where to insert the code on vhost

**File structure**
 public is moved to public_html and other folders to root directory